# Sqlite integer overflow while using BIGINT

Tags: sql, sqlite, bigint

Having a sqlite3 I would like to query and sum different values. The query I'm trying to do is:

```
SUM(CAST(amountA AS BIGINT)) as totalA, SUM(CAST(amountB AS BIGINT)) as totalB
```

When the query finds several results it will trigger:

```
error="integer overflow"
```

Looking at the docs of sqlite it appears that there isn't such a BIGINT, but instead, due affinity, the BIGINT is treated as an INTEGER.

Is it possible to SUM BIGINT numbers using sqlite3?

EDIT

The data type of `amountA` and `amountB` is TEXT. Changing it to INTEGER will trigger the same error when doing:

```
SUM(amountA) as totalA, SUM(amountB) as totalB
```

This is because the values I'm storing is `1000000000000000000` and when 10 values like those are stored, when summing them it will overflow as it overflows a 8 bytes signed integer

Comment: just curious: What is the data column definition that you feel a need to `cast` it? All integer types are treated as bigint in memory anyway? What happens when you sum the column directly? I would check that the `AmountA` column really does hold integer values in your table in the required range. I suspect that it is 'data value' error in a column rather than a `BIGINT` issue.

Comment: Sqlite has the concept of type affinity and bigint is considered integer, you will be better off by casting to Numeric or Decimal

Comment: Ohh I'm using TEXT. I guess I would need to change it to INTEGER then

Answer (score 2):

You should store integer values as `INTEGER` and not `TEXT`, but for your issue it would not make any difference.

When using aggregate functions like `SUM()` any string value that appears to be integer is implicitly converted to integer and if all summed values are integers then the resulting data type is also `INTEGER`.
It seems that the sum of your data exceeds the max 64bit integer value supported by SQLite which is `9223372036854775807` and you get `integer overflow`.

What you can do is sum the numbers as real numbers by casting each value to `REAL`:

```
SUM(CAST(amountA AS REAL)) as totalA, SUM(CAST(amountB AS REAL)) as totalB
```

Or use SQLite's `TOTAL()` aggregate function which sums the numbers as `REAL` and never throws an integer overflow:

```
TOTAL(amountA) as totalA, TOTAL(amountB) as totalB
```

You can read more about `SUM()` and `TOTAL()` here: [Built-in Aggregate Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect! The values might overflow the max 64bit integer so that's why I'm saving them as TEXT

Comment: @manolodewiner then you should use TOTAL() instead of SUM().

Answer (score 1):

[But as soon as INTEGER values are read off of disk and into memory for processing, they are converted to the most general datatype (8-byte signed integer)](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

If your sum fits into 64bit signed integer [-9223372036854775808 .. 9223372036854775807] it should be ok.
You needn't to cast int to bigint.

Quick demo

```
with cte(a) as (
      select 9223372036854775807 - 100 union all
      -- uncommenting next line will cause integer overflow
      --select 1 union all
      select 100
     )
select sum(a), typeof(sum(a)) t
from cte
```

Result

| sum(a) | t |
| --- | --- |
| 9223372036854775807 | integer |

Answer (score 0):

Please mention your data type of amountA and amountB column. Is it integer? I suspect not.

Casting should not be needed into bigint.

```
SUM(amountA ) as totalA, SUM(amountB) as totalB Should be ok.
```

But first please share sample data of amountA and amoutB column. I am afraid that the problem is not in sum() but the datatype of the column in that table.